# Setting root password

Tags: mysql

How do you set the root password in MySQL 5.6.16?

I have tries using:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpass') WHERE User='root';
```

But it's showing me: `Error 1064<42000>`

Comment: Which error is it showing?

Comment: Its telling me to check mysql manual. Error 1064<42000>

Comment: Are you literally typing `PASSWORD<'newpass'>`?  You need to use parenthesis (`()`), not angle brackets (`<>`).  `SET password=PASSWORD('newpass')`

Comment: @user3490152: Show us the *entire* error message, not just the error code.

Answer (score 3):

I think the command you are looking for is ["SET PASSWORD"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html).

For example it can be used like this:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD( 'newpass' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the table name is user not user.root
`update user set password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") where User='root'`;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update mysql.user set Password = PASSWORD('yourNewPass')
where User = 'root' and Host = 'localhost'
```

Comment: Its showing update command denied  to  user '@localhost' for table 'user'

Comment: are you logged into mysql console?